# Angular Unit Test Mock Replay Subject

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a service with a replay subject.

```
export class UserService {
  public userChanged: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>();

...
public getUser(userId?): void {
    ...
    this.http.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getUser', null, 'Couldn\'t get user', options))
    ).subscribe( (user: User) => {

       this.userChanged.next(user);

    });
  }
```

My component subscribes to `userChanged`.

```
this.userService.userChanged.subscribe((user) => {
  this.user = user;
});
```

Now, I want to mock my `UserService` in the component test:

1 option [Testing Observables in Angular](https://netbasal.com/testing-observables-in-angular-a2dbbfaf5329))

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
...
    const userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', {'userChanged': of({_id: '1'}) });
```

or 2 option)

```
    const userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', {'userChanged': () => of({_id: '1'}) });
```

or 3 option [angular test tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-with-a-spy))

```
const userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['userChanged']});
const userChangedSpy = userServiceSpy.userChanged.and.returnValue( of({_id: '1'})  );
```

+

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    {provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceSpy}
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

give me this err:

```
this.userService.userChanged.subscribe is not a function
```

Shouldn't `of` return an Observable to subscribe to?

Question: How to mock this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`createSpyObj` is used to to create spies on methods. You could use it for `getUser` method of `UserService`.

`userChanged` is just a property of the class. You don't need a spy for it.

What you can do is simply create a mock object that returns subject:

```
const userChanged = new Subject();

 providers: [
    ...
    {provide: UserService, useValue: { userChanged }}
  ],
```

*`{ userChanged }` is equal to `{ userChanged: userChanged }`*

Then, in your `beforeEach` block you would emit a new user instance:

```
//...
beforeEach(() => {
   const myUser = new User(...)
   userChanged.next(myUser)
})
```

I recommend to do this in the `beforeEach` block to avoid side effects between different specs.

```
 providers: [
    ...
    {provide: UserService, useValue: { userChanged: of({id: 1}) }}
  ],
```

---

Another way of doing the same would be simply creating observable using `of` method same way you're doing it in your example.

---

If you really want to spy on `subscribe` method, you can create spy on it:

`spyOn(userChanged, 'subscribe')`

---

If you want to mix `spyObject` with properties, you can use spread operator:

```
const spyObj = {
  ... jasmine.createSpyObj('MyObject', ['spyMethod']),
  myProperty: true,
};

spyObj.spyMethod();

expect(spyObj.spyMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(spyObj.myProperty).toBeTrue();
```

Comment: I had to change `.emit` to `.next` but it worked. Thanks. If I want to use this and spy on methods can I combine it e.g.: `{provide: UserService, useValue: { userChanged,  userServiceSpy}}`

Comment: Sorry for `.emit`. Always messing Subject with EventEmitter -_-.

Comment: For combining properties with spyObject you can use spread operator. Check updated answer

Comment: Hi @DDRamone. 
As per the above solution you're returning userChanged with an observable.
Could you please help, when we have multiple subjects written in a service?

Comment: @KarthikBhat You can add as many properties to the mock services as you need. Just separate them with commas as you would do in the normal object. If this doesn't answer your question, let me know more details and I will try to help.

Comment: @DDRamone: I was referring to the scenario when we have multiple subjects in the service that are injected to a component (and are Unit Testing the component).
My question is changing the below code :
providers: [
    ...
    {provide: UserService, useValue: { userChanged }}
  ],
to address multiple subjects, methods etc.,

Comment: @DDRamone: I was able to figure out. Please find my answer below. Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit late.. But I was able to resolve this issue by following the below approach:

```
1. mockUserService = TestBed.get(UserService)
2. By calling the subscribe method using :
mockUserService.userChanged.Subscribe(data => {
// do something
})
```

Note: Code at line 1 & 2 **must** sit anywhere after TestBed.configureTestingModule declaration.