# Mocking a Subject property of mocked service to be subscribed in the Angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, properties, jasmine, subject

In my Angular unit testing my mocked service has two properties:

```
  public messageChange: Subject<ChatMessage> = new Subject<ChatMessage>();
  public gameChange: Subject<GameState> = new Subject<GameState>();
```

And in my SUT I use them in my constructor:

```
this._subChat = this.hub.messageChange.subscribe((message: ChatMessage) => {
      this.message = message;
      this.messageChange.next(this.message);
    });
    this._subGame = this.hub.gameChange.subscribe((game: GameState) => {
      this.game.setGame(game);
    });
```

Right now I am trying to use these 2 approaches to mock properties from mocked service:

- [Angular Unit Test Mock Replay Subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55279477)
- [How to spyOn a value property (rather than a method) with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793575/12603542)

Riht now my testing looks like this:

```
describe('SignalRService', () => {
  let signalrService: SignalRService;
  const hubServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('HubConnectionService', [
    'isConnectionStarted',
  ]);
  const messageChange = new Subject();
  const gameChange = new Subject();

  beforeEach(() => {
    signalrService = new SignalRService(
      hubServiceMock
    );
    let msg = {} as ChatMessage;
    let gam = {} as GameState;
    messageChange.next(msg);
    gameChange.next(gam);
  });

  it('Service_ShouldBeCreated', () => {
    spyOnProperty(hubServiceMock, 'messageChange', 'get').and.returnValue(
      messageChange
    );
    spyOnProperty(hubServiceMock, 'gameChange', 'get').and.returnValue(
      gameChange
    );
    expect(signalrService).toBeTruthy();
  });
}
```

So in the test I create:

- service mock `hubServiceMock`,
- fake `messageChange = new Subject();`,
- fake `gameChange = new Subject();`,
- i run for both `.next`,
- and I setup spy for properties:

  `spyOnProperty(hubServiceMock, 'messageChange', 'get').and.returnValue( messageChange );`

  `spyOnProperty(hubServiceMock, 'gameChange', 'get').and.returnValue( gameChange );`

Why it does not work to me? I receive an error:

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `hubServiceMock` doesn't have the fake subjects in its `messageChange` and `gameChange`, you need to set them before calling `new SignalRService(hubServiceMock)`.

```js
  const hubServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('HubConnectionService', [
    'isConnectionStarted',
  ]);
  const messageChange = new Subject();
  const gameChange = new Subject();

  // add this
  hubServiceMock.messageChange = messageChange;
  hubServiceMock.gameChange = gameChange;
```

then it should work, maybe small adjustments are needed.

---

I would suggest to use a mocking lib for such cases to avoid pain.

For example with [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks), the test might look like:

```js
describe('SignalRService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(SignalRService, ITS_MODULE));

  const hubServiceMock = {
    messageChange: new Subject(),
    gameChange: new Subject(),
  };
  beforeEach(() => MockInstance(HubConnectionService, hubServiceMock));


  it('Service_ShouldBeCreated', () => {
    const signalrService = MockRender(SignalRService).point.componentInstance;
    expect(signalrService).toBeTruthy();

    hubServiceMock.messageChange.next({});
    hubServiceMock.gameChange.next({});
    // next assertions.
  });
}
```

Comment: I ended up with approach as above, and it looks working fine. What do you think about this?

Comment: The main thing is that it works for you. There are a lot of ways how to write tests.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with approach, where I inject mocked service like this:

```
hubServiceMock = TestBed.inject(HubConnectionService);
```

Then I mock my `Subject`s like this:

```
it('Service_ShouldBeCreated', () => {
    spyOn(hubServiceMock.messageChange, 'next');
    spyOn(hubServiceMock.gameChange, 'next');
    expect(signalrService).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

And in other tests I can use methods of mocked service like that:

```
let spyIsConnectionStarted = spyOn(hubServiceMock, 'isConnectionStarted');
    spyIsConnectionStarted.and.returnValue(true);
```